# Big disagreement on available disk space between df and du on mac os

Tags: macos

My Mac (10.14.6) is giving me a message that disk space is almost full. If I run df -h in the terminal I also see that disk space is almost full. However, when I run df -h at the computer level, it only comes to a fraction (about 33%) of the total disk space. Therefore, I can't find the files that I need to delete!

I've done numerous things including:
- running `du` as sudo and including hidden files at the top level of the system (i.e. `df -h /`)
- deleting docker for mac and its caches in ~/Library and in /Library

I get a similar picture to the command line df/du in Finder. The Get Info menu for the disk indicates 2 GB free, but when I do Get Info on everything in the disk (including hidden files) comes to much less than this (a similar value to what I get from du).

So either:
- there's hundreds of GB on my system that I can't find
- df and Finder are mistaken about how much of my disk is taken up

Help greatly appreciated as I'm hitting out of memory errors routinely and have deleted all the easy stuff already!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few tools that are better for this task, you can try **ncdu** which you can install with `brew install ncdu`, [Clean My Mac](https://cleanmymac.com) has a tool called **Space Lens**, I use [Daisy Disk](https://daisydiskapp.com) any of this tools will help you find where exactly are the biggest folders/files in your filesystem

Comment: Thanks @petrubear: clean my mac and ncdu give the same results as du indicating a lot of disk space left. Suggests that `df` might be wrong

Comment: OmniDiskSpace is great for it too